# Replace text of a column based on values from another table excel

Tags: excel

How can I formulate to change the text in a column based on predefined values from a different table?

```
  A   |  B     |  C
Office| Initial| Value
------|--------|-------
W     |  E     | Excel
E     |  Po    | Powerpoint
Po    |  W     | Word
```

How can I formulate `Column A` that if I write `W`, it'll automatically replace to `Word`, if I write `Po`, it'll be replaced into 'Powerpoint`?

I have looked for a while but couldn't figure out the right way to formulate it. How can I write the function for it?

Comment: You cant use a formula to replace the same cell's text! Look into VBA, or you can use another column to get your desired output.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use another column, how the formula might be? @JvdV

Comment: Check provided answer for that :)

Comment: If you want to use a column, you can't hardcode the choices in the formula. You can, for instance, use MATCH with wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the partial match of your entry in A1 with the values in column C, showing the result in column B, use this formula in column B:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($A1&"*",$C:$C,0),COLUMN($C$1)))
```

(Note: I used "COLUMN(C1)" instead of "3" so that it survives movement, copying, inserting columns, etc.)

For sanity, you could avoid searching when the search term is blank:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($A1&"*",$C:$C,0),COLUMN($C$1))))
```

Result:

```
  A  |B          |C
1 Po |Powerpoint |Excel
2 Ph |Photoshop  |Powerpoint
3 P  |Powerpoint |Word
4 Ex |Excel      |Photoshop
5 Ed |#N/A       |
```